# MVC3 DropDownListFor selected value does not change when set in postback action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I've read a lot of posts on here regarding the dropdown selected value issues (not showing etc etc...) but mine is the opposite problem.

I want the drop down to always reset after the view is returned after a button submits the page through the controller action. So how I've structured it all works but is it possible to reset the dropdown list each time? I can't find a way to do it and I've tried a lot of ways, believe me.

My View:

```
@Model.PspSourceModel.PayAccount.PaymentProviderId
<br />
@Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.PspSourceModel.PayAccount.PaymentProviderId,
            new SelectList(Model.PspSourceModel.PaymentProviders, "Value", "Text", "-- please select --"),
    "-- please select --"
```

My Controller:

```
// I've tried forcing the selected value id here - doesn't effect the dropdownlist still?
pspVM.PspSourceModel.PayAccount.PaymentProviderId = 1;

return (View(pspVM));
```

My Webpage shows:

```
1 (the id I set in the Action)

dropdownlist with the id=6 or whatever value was chosen prior to submitting the form.
```

From the questions and answers on SO and the wider web I thought the dropdownlist seems tied to the id you choose but how do I override that to reset the dropdown to 'please select' each time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just found a way of doing it but open to better suggestions?

// if I clear first and then set to a non existant Id (-1) it will default to the 'please select'

My Controller:
    
    `code`
    ModelState.Clear();

    pspVM.PspSourceModel.PayAccount.PaymentProviderId = -1;

    return (View(pspVM));
`code`


Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental problem here is that when MVC is rebinding the form on postback, it is not using Model but ModelState, so you can change your model as much as you like but only the bound ModelState will be used. Have you tried either of these methods on ModelState?

```
 public bool Remove(string key);
 public void SetModelValue(string key, ValueProviderResult value);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your action on your postback, you could process the current value as you need to and either set the id in the model and call the view;

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ModelClass viewModel)
{
  // Process Value

  viewModel.PspSourceModel.PayAccount.PaymentProviderId = 6;
  return View("Index", viewModel);
}
```

Or you could set the default values on your HttpGet, and call a RedirectToAction result in your post.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  // Set the default values; the following is a rough example, and won't work.
  var viewModel = new ModelClass
  {
    PspSourceModel.PayAccount.PaymentProviderId = 6
  }

  return View("Index", viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ModelClass viewModel)
{
  // Process Value

  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I hope this is clear, if you need further assistance, please let me know.

Matt

Comment: Thanks Matt, your HTTPost suggestion was exactly what I was doing. Somehow setting the Id in there doesn't solve my problem.

I can't do your Redirect solution either as I've got other stuff going on in there and the logic to avoid it would become messy.

Seems it's a **ModelState** issue as per my initial comment.

Thanks anyway